# Isometries of [0,1] with natural topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that metric space $([0,1], d)$ with natural topology has only one isometry other that identity. The hint in my book says that I should consider $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$.

This is what I've come up with:

$|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(0)|=|x- 0| = |x|$.

$f(x) \in [0,1] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x \in [0,1]$, so $f(x)=x$

This means that if $f(0)=0$, then $f = id$.

I know that $f$ is a homeomorphism, because it is an isometry (this gives us injection and uniform continuity) and $[0,1]$ is compact (surjection).

This means tht $f$ is strictly monotone. We know that if it is increasing, it must be that $f(0)=0$. So in order for it not to be identity, $f$ must be strictly decreasing, so we must have $f(0)=1, \ \  f(1)=0$ .

Do you think this proof is complete?

I would really appreciate all your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks good.  Perhaps mention that the other isometry is the function $f(x) = 1 - x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to show that the isometry $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ is unique, but that's essentially the same as what you did to show that $f(0)=0\Rightarrow f=\mbox{Id}$. Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to show that the isometry $f(x) = 1-x$ is unique?

Comment: I really can't think of any way which would be more simple. If $f(0)=1,f(1)=0$ and there exists some $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)\neq 1-x$, then $d(f(0),f(x))=d(1,f(x))\neq d(1,1-x)=d(0,x)$ because the only point z such that $d(1,z)=d(1,1-x)$ is $z=1-x$. Hence $f$ is not an isometry.